# how do I type the 3 bar with slash sign?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Please see attached picture.
How do I type the 3 bar equal sign with a slash on top of it?

[image]

When I copied the symbol from google and pasted it into my text editor, it doesn't recognize it with color, and shows like this.

[image]

The file is a jsx, React, JavaScript file.

Comment: In your editor, it's not the actual symbol. It's a ligature that you have setup with your IDE's font. The characters are actually simply `!==`

Comment: That's a font that shows `!==` as a single char. There are plenty of those out there, one of those is [FiraCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode#fira-code-free-monospaced-font-with-programming-ligatures)

Comment: [Cascadia Code](https://github.com/microsoft/cascadia-code) and [FiraCode](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) are popular mono-spaced fonts that provide ligatures that include this symbol

Comment: This is where knowledge of the underlying language constructs helps. JavaScript has no use for the `U+2262 ≢ NOT IDENTICAL TO` code point, and uses `!` for "not" and `===` for "identical to", and, when combined, elides one of the `=`, to produce `!==`.

Answer (score 0):

This is ligature. It is a special visualisation for a group of sequential characters.
In your case !==.

Legatures depends on your font configuration in your code editor.

For example in Intellij idea simply go to:

```
File -> Settings-> Editor -> Font -> Enable legatures
```

For VS Code there are several ways, one is to use this extention ([manual](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/enable-font-ligatures-in-vscode)):

```
Fira Code
```

Other editors also have FiraCode plugin, check out instrucions on [site](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki).

Comment: I assume "Fule" is supposed to be "File"?